# Hide/show content depending on selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, show-hide

I'm trying to make a form which contains a checkbox question of "yes" or "no". If the user answers the checkbox "yes", the rest of the form will show, but if the user answers "no" then the rest of the form will keep the hidden properties.

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Eliasperez/c3ay7jdy/2/

Both codes work great but I can't seem to make them work together. I'd love to have some help with this. I want the user to select one checkbox only and to have the fields hidden until the user checks the "yes" option. The "no" option should be checked by default. Feel free to ask for any further explanation or info.

```
<script>
   $("#CAT_Custom_1186889_1").change(function(){
   var self = this;
   $("#tableID tr.rowClass").toggle(!self.checked); 
   }).change();

   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
     $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
   });
</script>
<table id="tableID">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label class="label16">¿Cuentas con Embajador Blive?</label>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1186889" id="CAT_Custom_1186889_0" value="Si" class="boxcheck">Si &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1186889" id="CAT_Custom_1186889_1" value="No" class="boxcheck">No
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowClass">
         <td>This 2 rows will disapear! </td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="rowClass">
         <td>This 2 rows will disapear!</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Elias, the way in which you write your question conveys how much you care about getting an answer and how much you respect those who will provide the answer. Next time, please consider reviewing your post for basic spelling and grammatical issues. Punctuation is enormously helpful for the reader.

Comment: Use radio buttons if you want the user to be able to only make one selection.

Comment: Also, consider using CSS rather than `&nbsp;` and `<br>`. http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/12/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the if condition :

`if ($(this).val()=="Si"){/*Show the form*/}`

```js
$("#CAT_Custom_1186889_1").change(function(){
    var self = this;
    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").toggle(!self.checked); 
}).change();

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).val()=="Si"){
          $(".rowClass").show();
      }
      $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
    <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="label16">¿Cuentas con Embajador Blive?</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1186889" id="CAT_Custom_1186889_0" value="Si" class="boxcheck">Si &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1186889" id="CAT_Custom_1186889_1" value="No" class="boxcheck">No
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>This 2 rows will disapear! </td>
         
        </tr>
        <tr  class="rowClass">
            <td>This 2 rows will disapear!</td>
           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to only make one choice from several options, use radio buttons, not checkboxes. Users have certain expectations when it comes to the interface and using checkboxes would be counter-intuitive.

Here's the code you can use:

```js
$('input[name="CAT_Custom_1186889"]').change(function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log(this.value)
    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").css('display', (this.value == 'Si') ? 'block' : 'none');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="label16">¿Cuentas con Embajador Blive?</label>
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_1186889" id="CAT_Custom_1186889_0" value="Si" class="boxcheck">Si &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_1186889" id="CAT_Custom_1186889_1" value="No" class="boxcheck">No
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>This 2 rows will disapear!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>This 2 rows will disapear!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```